# Updating files for my static website on S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to update a static website I'm hosting on amazon AWS S3 - just need to put a new version of my resume up there. I've gone through the documentation and it seems as though I need to 'invalidate' the file - but all the guides I'm finding only talk about using cloudfront, which is a service I don't use.

So for a static website where I need to update a single file, how do I do that without cloudfront?

Comment: Usually you would only have to upload it on S3. I am pretty sure that you could just put the file in the bucket and you would be done! S3 doesn't have any cache, so the change should be instant.

Comment: Well I've tried a few times now but it doesn't seem to be updating. Waited over a week the first time around figuring it was just a cache issue but nothing updated. I've since tried uploading a new version of "resume.pdf", deleting the old version entirely and adding the new one, but nothing seems to work. Still the old file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload the file directly to S3 through the [AWS S3 Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/what-is-s3.html), programmatically using a package for [python](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/), [ruby](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/), etc., or using the [AWS Command Line](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

If you are using the [AWS Command Line](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), you can upload a file to s3 using these commands:

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE  
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY  
Default region name [None]: us-east-1  
Default output format [None]: json
$ aws s3 cp myvideo.mp4 s3://mybucket/
```

Comment: I've already updated the file in the S3 bucket, I just want the live version on my static website to be updated.

Comment: @Sierra117 I don't understand how *"So you may need to check in the AWS S3 Console to get the url for the new version of the object"* (which isn't correct advice based on anything presented in the question) leads to *"Thanks! Problem solved."*  What was the problem and how was it solved?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot S3 stores keys for each object's initial version, if you just take the base url you will only get the old object so to get the current version you need to get the version specfic url.

Comment: @mattjegan, I understand how S3 object versioning works, but you have it a bit backwards -- the base URL is always the *latest* version, not the original version, except for cases where there is a delay due to eventual consistency.  If there was a bucket index replication delay, the "solution" is just to "wait," but this is rarely necessary.  Particularly with a static site, version IDs would not typically be used.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yeah I missed the eventual consistency solution, you are correct.